# Wrong Implementation of Binary Search Tree's search Function

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, binary-search

I have a Binary Search Tree and I think one of my method is working incorrectly. The program I have is a program that separates the strings read from a file word by word and deletes the special characters in it, then transfers these words to the data structure in alphabetical order. If the same word was previously conveyed during the transmission, it increases the frequency of that word. While checking the output of my program, I saw something like this.

MY OUTPUT:

```
Readed Line: sun-meal            //After some operation it is seperated like "sun" and "metal"
    String inserted.
    String inserted.
Readed Line: sun-oil             //After some operation it is seperated like "sun" and "oil"
    String inserted.
    String inserted.             //Error is here.
```

TRUE OUTPUT SHOULD BE:

```
Readed Line: sun-meal                      //After some operation it is seperated like "sun" and "metal"
    String inserted.
    String inserted.
Readed Line: sun-oil                       //After some operation it is seperated like "sun" and "oil"
    String inserted.
    Repeated String. Frequency +1.         //It should be like that.
```

I will share my source code but what I want to know is what am I doing wrong? Why is "sun" inserted 2 times?

TreeDriver Class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TreeDriver
{
    public static void main(String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Tree stTree = new Tree();
        TreeNode compareNode;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));

        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            String data = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Readed Line: "+data);
            String[] convertedData = data.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", " ").toLowerCase().split("\\s+");
            int y = 0;
            try {
                while(convertedData[y] != null){
                    String st = convertedData[y];

                    if (st.contains(" ")) {

                    }
                    else{
                        compareNode = Tree.search(stTree.getRoot(), st);

                        if (compareNode != null) {
                            compareNode.upFreq();
                            System.out.println("\tRepeated String. Frequency +1.");
                        } else {
                            stTree.insert(st);
                            System.out.println("\tString inserted.");
                        }
                        y++;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ignored) {
            }
        }

        scan.close();
    }
}
```

TreeNode Class

```
public class TreeNode
{
    private int freq;   //frequency of the String in the Node
    private String stValue;
    private TreeNode left;
    private TreeNode right;

    public TreeNode(String st)
    {
        stValue = st;
        left = null;
        right = null;
        freq = 1;
    }

    public void add(String st)
    {
        if (left == null)
        {
            left = new TreeNode(st);
        }
        else if (right == null)
        {
            right = new TreeNode(st);
        }
        else
        {
            if(countNodes(left) <= countNodes(right))
            {
                left.add(st);
            }
            else
            {
                right.add(st);
            }
        }
    }

    //Count the nodes in the binary tree to which root points, and
    public static int countNodes( TreeNode root ) {
        if ( root == null )

            // The tree is empty.  It contains no nodes.
            return 0;

        else {

            // Start by counting the root.
            int count = 1;


            // Add the number of nodes in the left subtree.
            count += countNodes(root.getLeft());
            // Add the number of nodes in the right subtree.
            count += countNodes(root.getRight());

            return count;  // Return the total.
        }
    }

    public TreeNode getLeft(){
        return left;
    }

    public TreeNode getRight(){
        return right;
    }

    public String getString()
    {
        return stValue;
    }

    public void upFreq()
    {
        freq = freq + 1;
    }
    public int getFreq()
    {
        return freq;
    }

}
```

Tree Class:

```
public class Tree
{
    private TreeNode root;

    public Tree()
    {
        root = null;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return root == null;
    }

    public void insert(String st)
    {
        if (isEmpty())
        {
            root = new TreeNode(st);
        }
        else
        {
            root.add(st);
        }
    }

    public TreeNode getRoot()
    {
        return root;
    }

    public static TreeNode search(TreeNode root, String st)
    {
        if(root == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else if(st.equals(root.getString()))
        {
            return root;
        }
        else
        {   if (root.getLeft() != null)
            return search(root.getLeft(), st);
        else
            return search(root.getRight(), st);
        }
    }
    public TreeNode found(TreeNode root)
    {
        return root;
    }
    public static void preorderPrint(TreeNode root)
    {
        if ( root != null )
        {
            System.out.print( root.getString() + " " );  // Print the root item.
            preorderPrint( root.getLeft() );   // Print items in left subtree.
            preorderPrint( root.getRight() );  // Print items in right subtree.
        }
    }
}
```

Can you please help me find the problem?

Comment: Try to run the program in the debugger. You can single step throgh the code to see where it deviates from your expectations.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, your `search` function is wrong :

```
  if (root.getLeft() != null)
     return search(root.getLeft(), st);
  else
     return search(root.getRight(), st);
```

You are going through the right child node only if the left one is null, when you should go through both.